# Populating NSmutableDictionary error

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Greeting. I have a NSmutableDictionary and want to populate it.

```
- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {
    //NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //To add content and keys

    NSInteger numRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kNumComponent];//0=1st,1=2nd,etc
    NSInteger SeaRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kSeaComponent];//0=fall,1=spring,2=summer
    NSInteger CourseRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kCourseComponent];

    NSString *num=Number[numRow];
    NSString *season=Season[SeaRow];
    NSString *course=Course[CourseRow];

NSString *AddKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",num,season];

    [contents setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:course, nil] forKey:AddKey];
   // NSLog(@"%@", key);//test key here, it works
    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [contents description]);//test dictionary here

...}
```

Here, I have a button, when I push it, `num` and `season` and form a key, and the related `course` will be add to the dictionary. However, when I test it with

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [contents description]);
```

to show all the content in the dictionary, Only the last record in my selection is shown. In other words, when populating the dictionary, the previous data were override by the later one. What is the problem please?

Update: Thanks for Javier's advice. It fix this problem. But now in the new situation, only one key can hold one content. The following content will override the old one, why is that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSMutableDictionary *contents is not retained by any object of your controller and when the method finishes, that object will be released automatically .

Try declaring contents as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *contents;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to fix this problem. But when using this method, 1 key can only hold one content, the content will be overide, what to do please?

Comment: [contents setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:course, nil] forKey:AddKey];  sets a new array every time and thats wrong. You should extract the array related with the key first,then add to that array the object,and finally call setObject: with that array.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Could you please show me an example? much thanks.

Comment: Try this:  NSMutableArray *array = [contents objectForKey: AddKey];  
  [array addObject: course];
  [dic setObject:array forKey: AddKey];